# What is the relation between Operating system pages and Database pages?

Tags: database, operating-system

i know that in both cases its the smallest unit which they can work with, but i don't understand whats the relation between two of them?

i thought operating system decides what the page size is and the database works  on top of O.S and follows O.S rules? Isn't database just a process that is running in that O.S?

so what is the meaning of having an O.S with 4KB page size and a database with 8kb or vice versa?

why are databases not using the O.S page size?

Comment: You'll have to define what a database page size is. It sounds like you are refering to some specific database.

Comment: @user3344003 both mysql and sql server refer to something called page size in their documentation